# contradiction on completness of $C^0_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, piecewise-continuity

I am confused by the next problem:

> Show that the sequence
>
> $$f_n =
>   \begin{cases} 0 & 0\leqslant x<2-\dfrac{1}{n} \\ 1+n(x-2) & 2-\dfrac{1}{n}\leqslant x<2 \\ 1 & 2\leqslant x\leqslant 3 \end{cases}$$
>
> 1. is a Cauchy sequence.
> 2. find the limit
> 3. it is $C^{0}_{\infty}[0,3]$ (the space of continuous functions with domain $[0,3]$  a Banach space?

My confusion is that the limit is actually a non-continuous function, so it is a counterexample to say that $C$ is not a Banach space. However, I already know that it is a Banach space because $[0,3]$ is compact. Therefore, I am suspicious that it is not a Cauchy sequence but I don't know how to prove it, so any help?

the limit i get was

> $$f_n =
>   \begin{cases} 0 & 0\leqslant x<2 \\ 1 & 2\leqslant x \leqslant 3
> \end{cases}$$

Comment: What is $C^0_{\infty}[0,3]$?  What is the norm on this space?  What is the limit?  How is this limit take (i.e. with respect to what topology)?  What have you done (provide details, please)?

Comment: the space of continuous functions with domain [0,3] with the sup-norm

Comment: That is all valuable context which should be edited into the question.

Comment: i get the limit f(x)=0 if 0<x<2, 1 if 2 less/equal x less/equal 3

Comment: OK, sorry, i'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $m>n$. Then, since $2-\frac1n<2-\frac1{n+k}$, 
\begin{align}
f_{n+k}(2-\frac1{n+k})-f_n(2-\frac1{n+k})&=-f_n(2-\frac1{n+k})=-\left(1+n\left(2-\frac1{n+k}-2\right)\right)\\ \ \\
&=-\left(1-\frac n{n+k}\right).
\end{align}
So, for instance, if $k>n$, then 
$$
\|f_{n+k}-f_n\|\geq\frac12. 
$$
So the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: wow!! thank you so much, i was trying to do exactly that for so long time, but never got it...